# PHP Session lost after migrating from 5.6 to 7.1 (memcache)

Tags: php, session, memcached

After migrating a very old application from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.1, we have seen an increase of sessions that are lost (you are logged in in the application, and then after X minutes, you must login because session is no longer found in the memcache instance). This issue was *not* present on PHP 5.6

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = kyoto.master0:11211?persistent=1&;weight=1&;timeout=1&;retry_interval=15
```

[image: memcached configuration]
[image]

**Do you see anything that could explain that session are removed in an unwanted way from memcache since the migration on PHP 7.1 ?**

Thanks